Display image in addon
I was trying to display an image inside an addon.
to display the image I'm doing:
layout.template_preview(img)
but the image is not displayed. I'm using blender 4.2 and this is the code that I'm using:
bl_info = {
    "name": "Render Preview Addon",
    "description": "Displays a box with the rendered image of the current scene.",
    "author": "Your Name",
    "version": (1, 0, 1),
    "blender": (3, 0, 0),
    "location": "View3D > Sidebar > Render Preview",
    "category": "Render",
}

import bpy
import os

RENDER_PREVIEW_IMAGE_NAME = "Render_Preview"

class RENDER_OT_SaveImage(bpy.types.Operator):
    """Render and save the current scene as an image"""
    bl_idname = "render.save_preview_image"
    bl_label = "Render Scene"
    
    def execute(self, context):
        # Set the output path for the rendered image
        render_path = bpy.path.abspath("//render_preview.png")
        context.scene.render.filepath = render_path
        
        # Render the image
        bpy.ops.render.render(write_still=True)
        
        # Load or update the image in Blender's data
        if RENDER_PREVIEW_IMAGE_NAME in bpy.data.images:
            img = bpy.data.images[RENDER_PREVIEW_IMAGE_NAME]
            img.filepath = render_path
            img.reload()
        else:
            img = bpy.data.images.load(render_path)
            img.name = RENDER_PREVIEW_IMAGE_NAME
        
        self.report({'INFO'}, f"Image saved and loaded: {render_path}")
        return {'FINISHED'}

class RENDER_PT_PreviewPanel(bpy.types.Panel):
    """Creates a Panel to display the render preview"""
    bl_label = "Render Preview"
    bl_idname = "RENDER_PT_preview_panel"
    bl_space_type = 'VIEW_3D'
    bl_region_type = 'UI'
    bl_category = 'Render Preview'

    def draw(self, context):
        layout = self.layout
        
        # Add a button to render the scene
        layout.operator("render.save_preview_image", text="Render Scene")
        
        # Display the preview image if it exists
        img = bpy.data.images.get(RENDER_PREVIEW_IMAGE_NAME)
        if img:
            layout.label(text="antes.")
            layout.template_preview(img)
            layout.label(text="despues.")
        else:
            layout.label(text="Render the scene to see the preview.")

def register():
    bpy.utils.register_class(RENDER_OT_SaveImage)
    bpy.utils.register_class(RENDER_PT_PreviewPanel)

def unregister():
    bpy.utils.unregister_class(RENDER_OT_SaveImage)
    bpy.utils.unregister_class(RENDER_PT_PreviewPanel)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    register()

Does anyone know how this should be done?
thanks

Please use python and/or scripting tags when asking about scripting. Some people use tags for filtering questions.

You can use the icon_id of the image with bpy.types.UILayout.icon
This code will display the image icon of the size you want, from the image bpy.data.images
image = bpy.data.images['My Image']

icon_id = bpy.types.UILayout.icon(image)

layout.template_icon(icon_value=icon_id)

In order to adjust the size of the icon:
To change the icon size:
layout.template_icon(icon_value=icon_id, scale=2)

From Blender API docs
